# Every Java Program Giving Output of "B"

Tags: java, eclipse, console

Every Java program I run in eclipse, no matter how different, gives a console output of an uppercase "B". Does anyone know what is causing this?

UPDATE: Fixed the issue, turns out eclipse was using the previous programs run configurations instead of creating a new one for each program, so the console was just giving an output of another program I had ran earlier

Comment: Interesting, never heard of something like that

Comment: Which console is active? My Eclipse's Console tab shows "Java Stack Trace Console," "Maven Console," "SVN Console" and "New Console View" among others.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the default console is active

Comment: Make sure that you start the correct run configuration.

Comment: I have checked the run configuration and it seems ok

Comment: Try running a program that'll will fail with an exception (i.e. let the first command be 1/0 or something) and see if that gets thrown. If not your run configuration isn't correctly configured

Comment: Can you show a small example? With the run configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that you have set up that "invoke the same thing as last time", but if not, then your Eclipse installation is most likely so broken that you should just unpack it again and create a new workspace.

Comment: I figured it out just as you posted your answer, but yeah you were right